# How to update a field of an object in array of array in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

My mongodb data is like this,a little complicated because of array in array.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e36950f65fae21293937594"),
"userId" : "5e33ee0b4a3895a6d246f3ee",
"notes" : [ 
    {
        "noteId" : ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375a0"),
        "time" : ISODate("2020-02-02T17:24:06.460Z"),
        "memoryLine" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375ab"),
                "memoryTime" : ISODate("2020-02-03T17:54:06.460Z"),
                "hasReviewed": false
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375aa"),
                "memoryTime" : ISODate("2020-02-03T05:24:06.460Z"),
                "hasReviewed": false
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

I want to update hasReviewed in memoryLine with _id.For example, i want to update `_id:ObjectId(5e36953665fae212939375ab)` item's **hasReviewed** to **true** . As expected like below :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e36950f65fae21293937594"),
"userId" : "5e33ee0b4a3895a6d246f3ee",
"notes" : [ 
    {
        "noteId" : ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375a0"),
        "time" : ISODate("2020-02-02T17:24:06.460Z"),
        "memoryLine" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375ab"),
                "memoryTime" : ISODate("2020-02-03T17:54:06.460Z"),
                "hasReviewed": true    <============here updated to true
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375aa"),
                "memoryTime" : ISODate("2020-02-03T05:24:06.460Z"),
                "hasReviewed": false
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

How to deal with it?Thank you.

Comment: We can update using $pull function, firstly we can pull node after add push node

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar Can you write an example?Thank you.

Comment: your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **arrayFilters** in [.updateOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) to do this :

```
db.collection.update({ 'notes.memoryLine._id': ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375ab") },
    { $set: { "notes.$[].memoryLine.$[element].hasReviewed": true } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "element._id": ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375ab") }] })
```

**Note :** Since **memoryLine** is an array inside an object of **notes** array then this `notes.$[]` would update all objects **memoryLine.hasReviewed** to **true** when criteria is matched, in other case if you wanted to update just first matched object you can use `notes.$`. Also instead of `.updateOne()` you can use  `.updateMany()` to update multiple documents.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for this.

```
db.notes.updateOne({
    userId:"5e33ee0b4a3895a6d246f3ee",
    'notes.0.memoryLine._id': ObjectId("5e36953665fae212939375ab"),
}, {
    '$set': {
        'notes.0.memoryLine.$.hasReviewed': true
    }
});
```